# Will Wave Analytics become part of Standard reporting soon/ever?

Tags: reporting, dashboard, analytics, einstein-analytics

Wave Analytics is an amazingly easy to use and flexible way to analyse Salesforce data. Lightyears more advanced than the current standard reporting and dashboard functionality.

**Are there official plans, rumors and roadmaps to integrate Wave with the Platform's current old fashioned reporting capabilities?**

Answer (score 3):

The Lightning Experience is bringing the **Presentation Layer** of Wave / Analytics cloud into standard Salesforce Reports & Dashboard.

But the **Backend Analytics engine** of Wave / Analytics cloud will not be included into standard salesforce and will need a separate license / purchase

here's the snippet from [Lightning Experience FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Experience_FAQ)

**Q: Do the reports and dashboards in Lightning Experience use Wave Analytics?**

> A: Lightning reports and dashboards use Wave Analytics charting to
>   give them a new, modern look and feel. However, the reports and
>   dashboards do not leverage the Wave reporting engine. The query engine
>   has not changed.

Comment: Never say never ;-)

Comment: and pay for ever :-0

Comment: The output is Nice but the Input is a real Game changer!